# Segmentation violation signal in unidirectional list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a unidirectional list with nodes containing a value and a pointer to the next node (the pointer in the final node is supposed to be a nullptr).

Howerver, things are not going as planed. It's compiling without any problems, but when I try to run it i get this fatal error condition:
  SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal.

It think it's trying to reach memory which it doesn't have permission to use, or something? Another common cause is an accidental "=" instead of "==", but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

It seems that the error occurs when I try to construct a Sorted_List without any nodes in my test file, like this:

```
Sorted_List empty_list{};
```

Here is the code I imagine can be relevant to the error:

Sorted_List.cc

```
#include "Sorted_list.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

Sorted_List::Sorted_List() : head{nullptr} {}

Sorted_List::Sorted_List(initializer_list<int> i)
  :Sorted_List()
{
  for (auto ii : i)
    {
      add_val(ii);
    }
}

Sorted_List::~Sorted_List()
{
  if (!check_empty())
    {
      Node* del = head;
      while(del != nullptr)
    {
      Node* next = del->next;
      delete del;
      del = next;
    }
    }
}

bool Sorted_List::check_empty() const
{
  return (head->value == 0 && head->next == nullptr);
}


void Sorted_List::del_val(int num)
{
  Node* del = head;
  if (num == 1)
  {
    head = del->next;
    delete del;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < num - 1; i++)
    {
      del = del->next;
    }
}

void Sorted_List::add_val(int num)
{
  Node* temp = new Node;
  temp->value = num;
  if (head == nullptr || head->value >= temp->value)
    {
      temp->next = head;
      head = temp;
    }    
  else
    {
      Node* current = head;
      while(current->next != nullptr && current->next->value <temp->value)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }
      temp->next = current->next;
      current->next = temp;
    }
}
string Sorted_List::print( Sorted_List& list)
{
  Sorted_List::Node* temp;
  stringstream list_stream;
  for(temp = list.head; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next) 
    {
      list_stream << temp->value;
      if(temp->next != nullptr)
    list_stream << ", ";
    }
  return list_stream.str();
}
```

Sorted_List.h

```
#ifndef SORTED_LIST_H
#define SORTED_LIST_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

class Sorted_List
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int value{};
        Node* next{};
    };
Node* head{};

public:
    Sorted_List();
    Sorted_List(std::initializer_list<int>);
    ~Sorted_List();

    std::string print(Sorted_List&);
    void add_val(int num);
    bool check_empty() const;
    void del_val(int num);
};

#endif
```

Sorted_List_test.cc

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "Sorted_list.h"
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

TEST_CASE(" EMPTY ")
{  
  Sorted_List empty_list{}; // this is where the error occurs
  //REQUIRE(empty_list.check_empty() == true);
  //REQUIRE(empty_list.print(empty_list) == "");
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: In future, to solve problems like this, read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a debugger you will see that the crash happens when the `empty_list` object is *destructed*. More precisely in the `check_empty` function called from the destructor.

This is because the default constructor sets `head` to a null pointer, and then in the `check_empty` you dereference this null pointer.

Your `check_empty` function should check if `head` is a null pointer.